# Why is Swift's Character type not Hashable?

Tags: ios, swift

Is there some good reason Swift's Character type does not conform to the Hashable protocol by default. I find a lot of cases when I would like to use it as a dictionary key and then I always have to add this seemingly silly extension:

```
extension Character: Hashable {
    var hashValue: Int {
    return String(self).hashValue
    }
}
```

Comment: who knows, the language is still just a _concept_ and compiler is still just a _beta_.

Comment: [submit a bug to Apple](http://bugreport.apple.com) if you think it is important to have that built in.

Comment: For sure I will submit a bug for it but it seems like such an obvious thing to have built in that I'm wondering if I missed some reason for this not being a trivial addition.

Comment: My guess is that a Character isn't a real object.

Comment: As of Swift 1.0 Character is Hashable.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating an extension, it's probably a lot easier just to put your character keys in Strings.

Comment: Indeed, but writing String(char) gets really old.